# How to load 3DLUT on DSLR?

Tags: dslr, effect

There are few film emulation LUTs ([LookUp Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Lookup_tables_in_image_processing)) that I would like to use on my DSLR in real-time (live) because shooting live with LUT applied gives very accurate results and cuts down time on post editing process.

I would like to know if there are any ways to use LUTs live on DSLR just like you can with some smartphone apps.

Comment: LUTs are more commonly used for video rather than stills. You might get better answers over at our sister site [video.se]

Comment: Duplicate of http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/how-to-load-3d-luts-on-dslr

Comment: You create [your own "picture controls"](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/163/Picture_Control_Utility_2.html) for Nikon cameras.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by doing this? Do you also want the LUT applied to the footage before you import it into your computer for editing? Do other cameras like the Black Magic or RED allow you to apply a LUT during filming?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there are any ways to use LUTs live on DSLR just like the Smartphone camera filter apps does.

There are none.